# Unable to use RF M4 Receiver with servo motor

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, adafruit, button, rf

I am trying to control a servo motor with the following code:

```c
#include <Servo.h>

Servo servo;

int const inputPin = 3;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  servo.attach(9);
  pinMode(inputPin, INPUT);
  servo.write(0);
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(inputPin)) {
    Serial.println("HIGH");
    servo.write(40);
  } else {
    Serial.println("LOW");
    servo.write(0);
  }
}
```

It takes input from pin 3 and controls the servo with pin 9. When pin 3 is connected to a pushbutton, as shown in the following image, it works exactly as expected; for as long as the button is held down, the servo stays at 40° and when the button is released the servo returns to 0°.

It's a little difficult to see in the images, but the resistor on row 24 is connected to ground, not power.
[image]

However, if I replace the button with an Adafruit RF M4 Receiver, as shown in the following image, the servo behaves differently. When I hold the button on the remote down, the servo attempts to move to 40°, but returns to 0° before trying again. From the serial output, I can see that the pin is in fact oscillating between HIGH and LOW.
[image: Circuit with receiver]

If I remove the commands to the servo and just use the buttons to control the serial output, the code behaves correctly. With both the pushbutton and the RF M4 Receiver, the output says HIGH when the button is held down and LOW when it is released. So the issue only occurs when I use both the receiver and a servo motor, but not one or the other.

```c
int const inputPin = 3;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(inputPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(inputPin)) {
    Serial.println("HIGH");
  } else {
    Serial.println("LOW");
  }
}
```

I am using an Arduino Uno R3, [this receiver](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1096), and [this remote](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1095).

Edit: The schematic, as requested. I'm new to Arduino, so I apologize if the schematic is a little sloppy.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL5WtY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I will guess you probably have RF feedback getting into the control loop. No idea of how it gets there. Please post an annotated schematic.

Comment: @Gil, I'm working on making the schematic. Do you think I need the pull down resistor for the RF receiver? Can that be causing the issue?

Comment: No sure, I am not familiar with the parts or circuit you are using.  If that is connected to an Arduino port pin that can switch it low or high.

Comment: remove the servo and the servo code... light an LED instead

Comment: @jsotola It works as expected with an LED. I'm only having an issue when I'm using the receiver to control a servo.

Comment: @Gil, I've added a schematic. It's a little messy, but it's about the best I can do at this point. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: "From the serial output, I can see that the pin is in fact oscillating between HIGH and LOW." - Sounds like the receiver is not outputting a `HIGH` signal the entire time the button is being pressed, or maybe, the current requirement of both loads exceeds the Uno's available current.

Comment: @VE7JRO, The receiver normally outputs a HIGH signal the entire time the button is pressed except for when I use it with a servo, so the load requirement explanation sounds plausible. As a beginner, what would be some steps I can take to troubleshoot this? Would powering the servo with a separate battery fix the issue? I'm new to this, so I'm still not quite sure how to manipulate voltages and currents.

Comment: Powering the servo with a separate battery MAY solve the problem. Remember to connect the external power supply's ground with your Arduino's ground connection.

Comment: @VE7JRO I just tried it out and it worked. I connected the servo to a 9V battery and it operated correctly. I thought it might also work if I power the Arduino and the servo with the same 9V battery, since the voltage is higher that the Arduino's 5V, but the issue persisted when I did that, so I guess for now I just have to run them with different power sources. Is it standard practice to power servos with a separate power source? I know that that's the standard with DC motors, but the starter book I'm using didn't say anything about servos.

Comment: "Is it standard practice to power servos with a separate power source?" - Yes. If you look at the servo's power consumption under certain conditions, you'll see it can reach 730mA. Here is a chart for the SG90 servo: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/49755/37523 A 9 volt battery may not last very long, so you may want to switch to larger batteries or perhaps a wal-wart (AC to DC converter).

Comment: @VE7JRO Thank you for your help. As with the user in the question you linked to, I've been following official Arduino tutorials from the starter kit, and in all the projects that use a servo they connect it directly to the Arduino's power. They only discuss separate power sources for DC motors. For some reason, the tutorials are just not making this clear at all for beginners.